# In Angular CLI (1.3+) How can I ensure that my web.config file outputs to my 'dist' directory

Tags: angular, angular-cli, project-settings

In order to copy any file like a `favicon.ico` or a `web.config` from my Angular CLI project out to my dist folder upon running my production build command: `ng build --env=prod`, where do I have to put my file that I want copied and do I need to reference it in my `.angular-cli.json` file?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A few things you must remember when outputting files to your dist directory.

Ensure that the file you want exported already exists in your `src` directory. If you have both a `favicon.ico` and a `web.config` file that you want to output to the root of the `dist` directory they need to be in the root of your `src` directory.

Next you need to make a change to `.angular-cli.json` like so:

```
"apps": [
    {
      "root": "src",
      "outDir": "dist",
      "assets": [
        "assets",
        "favicon.ico",
        "web.config"
      ],
      ...
    }
  ],
```

Comment: Just a note that I did as suggested but I got following error after trying to build the app "An unhandled exception occurred: The web.config asset path must start with the project source root." I added full path like "src/web.config" and it worked. Thanks Eric
p.s. to all readers which had a problem with page refresh, if hosting on IIS, ensure that you set url with backslash like this url="\index.html".

Comment: Yes, this works, but does need the "src/" in the paths. Also a note for tuture readers, the file is called angular.json since Angular 6.